# Some module is not included when compile main.js in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Here is my `config` file

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "./src",
    paths: {
        "jQuery": "../lib/jquery"
    }
});
```

then I require it in `main.js`:

```
require(["./config"], function () {
    require(["./foo", "./bar", "jQuery"], function (Foo, Bar, $) {

    })
})
```

at last I use `build.js` to compile

```
({
    mainConfigFile: './config.js',
    paths: {
        "main": '../main',
        "config": '../config'
    },  
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js"

})
```

but in the `main-built.js` file, it only contains `config.js` and `main.js`:

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Uglifying file: /main-built.js

/main-built.js
----------------
/config.js
/main.js
```

Why the `foo` or the `bar` module is not included? How can I make it included?